# Magento SEO Pagination like /page/2

Tags: magento, pagination, seo

i am trying to play around with pager.phtml, basicaly i do not like the ?p=2 etc that magento use.
I have come through this code that will change the pagination to what i want but this brings of course 404 pages as there is no /page/2 etc. 
Should i use a rewrite rule?Can somebody point me on this?

```
<div class="pages">
    <strong><?php
    $url=   ($this->getCurrentPage()==1)?
    $this->getPagerUrl(array($this->getOrderVarName()=>$order,  $this->getDirectionVarName()=>$direction,$this->getPageVarName()=>null )).'/':
    $this->getPagerUrl(array($this->getOrderVarName()=>$order,  $this->getDirectionVarName()=>$direction,$this->getPageVarName()=>null )).'/';
     echo $this->__('Page:') ?></strong>
    <ol>
    <?php if (!$this->isFirstPage()): ?>
        <li>
            <a class="previous<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?> i-previous<?php endif;?>" 
            href="<?php echo $url.'p='.($this->getCurrentPage()-1);?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>">
                <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForPrevious()): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_left.png') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Previous') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php
    $pages_Num= ($this->getTotalNum()%$this->getLimit())?(($this->getTotalNum()/$this->getLimit())+1):$this->getTotalNum()/$this->getLimit();
    for($_page=1;$_page<=$pages_Num;$_page++){
        if($this->getCurrentPage()==$_page) echo '<li class="current"><a class="current" href="'.$url.'page/'.$_page.'">'.$_page.'</a></li>';
        else    echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'page/'.$_page.'">'.$_page.'</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php if (($this->getCurrentPage()+1)<$pages_Num): ?>
        <li><a class="next<?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?> i-next<?php endif; ?>" 
        href="<?php echo $url.'p='.($this->getCurrentPage()+1);?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>">
                <?php if(!$this->getAnchorTextForNext()): ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/pager_arrow_right.png') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Next') ?>" class="v-middle" />
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getAnchorTextForNext() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </a></li>
    <?php endif;?>
    </ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a custom router which will parse the requested URL.

The method match () of the router may be implemented with this piece of code like this:

```
public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request) {
    $this->_beforeModuleMatch();

    $url = $request->getRequestUri();

    $suffix = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/category_url_suffix');
    $pagerUrlFormat = "\/page\/([0-9]+)";
    if (preg_match('/' . $pagerUrlFormat . preg_quote($suffix, '/') . '/', $url, $match)) {
        $url = str_replace($match[0], $suffix, $url);
        $request->setRequestUri($url);

        $path = $request->getPathInfo();
        $path = str_replace($match[0], $suffix, $path);
        $request->setPathInfo($path);
        $request->setParam('p', $match[1]);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This code will generate a URL of such a kind: http://example.com/category/p/2.html

NB! Please note that the code above hasn't been tested. It's just a simplified version of the more advanced code that is used in our SEO module ([SEO Suite Ultimate](http://www.mageworx.com/seo-suite-ultimate-magento-extension.html))

Here is the description of the feature that does what you actually need:

> Ability to create a pager URL format for paginated pages  Examples:
>
> -page[page_number] will transform URL into /mobile-phones-page2.html /p/[page_number] will transform URL into /mobile-phones/p/2.html